# how to move a camera in 2d using opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, orthographic

I'm a beginner in OpenGL, and I'm trying to make a game where the camera has to move with the player while using 2D only. I thought that I could do this by updating `gluOrtho2D`, but it's not working, as the player goes out of the window and it just got disappears and world window is not updated. Here is the code:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D( m.pos_X - 600, m.pos_X + 600, m.pos_Y - 600 , m.pos_Y + 600 );
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

Comment: Conceptually, this code could work. Where is this called? BTW, you should be aware that all of the GL functions in your code snipped are deprecated - and not available in modern OpenGL. If you are learning OpenGL, I'd strongly recommend to learn the modern way with programmable pipeline instead of the 20 year old fixed function stuff.